# Google Chrome not rendering overflow correctly

Tags: asp.net, html, css, google-chrome, overflow

I just found this ASP.Net server control horizontal scroll not working when `align=right` attribute is used! I digged into the HTML generated code and found something like this:

```
<div align="right" style="overflow:scroll; width: 200px; height:200px;">
    <div style="width:400px; height:400px">
    </div>
</div>
```

The horizontal scrollbar appears the moment you remove the `align="right"` attribute.
Tested in Chrome 17/18. It works fine in Firefox 10 and IE 10

Any workaround?

PS.
Should I submit the bug to google chrome folks? This sounds to be a webkit bug!

Comment: What doctype are you using? I don't think the `div` element has the `align` attribute anymore.

Comment: It's not a bug.  The `align` attribute has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using CSS (`float:right;`) and doing away with the align attribute solves the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/rdjRS/

Is this what you were aiming for?

---

Update: I'm assuming you can add javascript, but you can't take away javascript. Could you try including this code into your javascript? It floats the element right and then removes the deprecated align attribute.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"L></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
​        $('[align="right"]')​.css('float', 'right').removeAttr('align');​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    </script>
```

Yes, it depends on jQuery.

As you see, it works without having you removing any HTML or CSS that was already there.
http://jsfiddle.net/hLg73/

Comment: I could use text-align css property, however I'm with no access to the server control, the server control is a third party UI component which we use in an ASP.Net form!

Comment: So what can you control? The CSS? Javascript?

Comment: The html code is generated dynamically by a JavaScript class at runtime, I believe I need to hack the Render method of the JS class to change the behavior! Worth a try, however I don't like the solution

Comment: Yes David, that worked, with a bit of change in the component's Render method...I had to overwrite Render method doing what it was doing plus the code above...thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `div` attribute, `align` has been deprecated...

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2

Therefore, I don't believe you can blame a browser bug when things don't render properly.

I would recommend using CSS to achieve this effect, such as `float: right;` as one example.